What's the smallest sudoku that can be solved trivially, for some meaning of trivial?
This question was motivated by my musing about how to store the solution to a standard 9x9 sudoku in a reasonably compact form. While it's possible to solve a solvable sudoku quickly with a computer by backtracking, I was interested in formats that could be solved in just one or two steps, perhaps in your head as quickly as you might copy the digits by hand from a page. Rather than try to define what I mean by 'trivial', I'll show two examples.
The full solution is on the left. My first attempt in the middle saves 21 cells. First each of the four top left blocks is completed. Then the 9th column, then the 9th row. This is trivial in the sense that all the results can be written straight down, with no need for memory or pencil marks. Neglecting the four cells in the blocks, the simple reduction of rows and columns down to an 8x8 yields a nice computer friendly 64 cells, or 60 if we make all the savings.
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 .      . . . 4 5 6 7 8 9
4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3     4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 .      . . . 7 8 9 1 2 3
7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6     7 8 . 1 2 . 4 5 .      . . . 1 2 . 4 5 .
9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8     9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 .      9 1 2 . . . 6 7 8
3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2     3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 .      3 4 5 . . . 9 1 2
6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5     6 7 . 9 1 . 3 4 .      6 7 . . . . 3 4 .
8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7     8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 .      8 9 1 2 3 4 . . .
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1     2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 .      2 3 4 5 6 7 . . . 
5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4     . . . . . . . . .      5 6 . 8 9 . . . .

My second attempt on the right saves 33 cells. First the six blocks are completed. Then the empty three blocks are completed with the intersections of the row and column candidates. This is slightly less trivial, but it can still be completed in one go without pencil marks or memory. Consider the first column, it's missing a '1', which can be written down directly in the first row, because rows 2 and 3 contain a '1'. The remaining 48 cells is still a relatively computer friendly number.
I've not considered any symmetries or sets yet.
Are there any ways to store a solution with fewer clues, that can still be reconstructed as in the above exemplars in a single manual process per cell?

I'm not sure this can be answered well without a more precise definition of "obvious". There's no clear distinction between what can be done by inspection and what requires pencil marks, and anything a backtracking solver does can be seen as an application of some non-backtracking rule.

@Karl I hope I've tightened the language up a little. In the title, 'for some meaning of trivial' was intended to invite some discussion on that, some suggestions of algorithms that you might consider trivial.
